# Does RUnit support XML output?

Tags: r

When running unit tests in Python code, the nosetests tool supports a --with-xunit command line flag which causes it to write a nosetests.xml file suitable for ingestion by (at least) Bamboo, perhaps by other continuous integration/deployment systems. It there something similar for RUnit or other unit testing frameworks for R?

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging showed that RUnit has both printHTMLProtocol and printTextProtocol functions, but nothing obviously like printXMLProtocol. The documentation also mentions XML output as a hoped for future improvement. I punted and wrote a simple Python script which munches on the output of printTextProtocol to construct an extremely basic XML file. Bamboo seems to like it, so I won't go further.